# I am getting "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BarcodePickerController" error while integrating red laser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

### Complete description of error

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BarcodePickerController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

### clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please give some idea..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The file doesn't exist or isn't being compiled.  Plain and simple.

Comment: looks to me you are not incorporating the red laser sdk properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your are using RedLaser SDK, but you forgot to link the SDK to your project.